# strategies when memory limits matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I need to calculate `sum(foo(x(:)*y),2))`, where `x` is a 1-D vector (1x1000) and `y` is a 1-D vector(1x1e8), both not sparse, and `foo` is composed of several trig functions that are not separable or have a summation rule (see edit at the end of the question).   For efficiency I made the vectors to be Single-precision arrays. Another info that may or may not be important is that `x` is just a monotonically increasing vector such as `x=linspace(0,1,1000)`.

Trying to to `x(:)*y`  I got into a memory problem. So I thought I'll do a for loop.

```
for i=1:length(y)
    A=A+sum(foo(x(:)*y(i)),2);
end
```

This is inefficient and takes forever, so I thought of breaking down the sum into several chunks of similar size (beside the last one which may be slightly different size) :

```
        nn = 10 ;% # of chunks 
        idN=length(y);
        splitn = floor(idN/nn);
        split = [1:splitn:idN];

        for i=1:nn-2
            A=A+sum(foo(x(:)*y(split(ni): split(ni)+splitn-1)),2)   
        end

        A = A +sum(foo(x(:)*y(split(nn-1):end)),2);
```

This takes a lot of time but is not forever (~45 min). What else can I do to make this faster besides buying a new computer? I dont think that `parfor` will help as there is only a certain amount of memory anyway. Does the # of chunks matter at all as long as it is all contained in memory per iteration?
Any strategy or suggestion in improving this multiplication will be great.

Edit:

I was a little careless in my original minimal example. the real question is not about simply `sum(x(:)*y,2)` but more like a `sum(foo(x(:)*y),2)`. there's no simple way to avoid the matrix multiplication. Sorry again for not making this clear.

Comment: Surely this is equal to `x(:)*sum(y)`, right?

Comment: Its always a game of memory efficiency vs computational efficiency, there is no magic trick that will make it both memory and computational efficient, because if there was, that would be the default.

Comment: I usually follow your chunk-based approach, with chunks as large as memory allows

Comment: Maybe you could provide some pseudo-code explaining what you're actually calculating here for those of use who don't know matlab syntax. There might be some algorithmic change that could reduce the amount of memory you need at any one time.

Comment: In your loop, `A=A+sum(x(:)*y(i),2);` is the same as `A=A+x(:)*y(i);`. You could also iterate over `x` instead, which is much shorter, and do `A(i)=sum(x(i)*y)`. This latter expression is the same as `x(i)*sum(y)`, where `sum(y)` doesn’t change and can be pre-computed before the loop. But now we see that this is the same as the loopless `A=x(:)*sum(y)`, as @beaker already noted.

Comment: @SimonGoater We're given two (row) vectors *x* and *y* with lengths *m* and *n* respectively. `x(:)` turns the row vector into a column vector. With MATLAB's explicit expansion, `x(:)*y` results in an mxn matrix with each row *i* given by `x(i)*y`. `A = sum(foo, 2)` sums each row of the matrix `foo`, giving a column vector of length *m*.

Comment: @beaker I was sick for a few days so I couldn't reply. I was a little careless in my minimal example. it is not simply `sum(x(:)*y,2)` but more `sum(foo(x(:)*y),2)`. there's no simple way to avoid the matrix multiplication. Sorry again for not making this clear.

Comment: I guess it largely depends on what `foo` does, then. Not only in deciding whether the function can be vectorized, but also in determining whether 45 minutes is reasonable. I mean, if you're doing 1e8 operations, that's only 2.7e-5 seconds per function call. What does `foo(x(:)*y(i))` return? If it is still a scalar, then as @Cris said, the `sum` in your first loop does nothing but add overhead.

Comment: I agree with @beaker. You might have to optimize `foo()`. It’s working on 1e11 elements, and if each column is a series of monotonically increasing values, you might be able to save some effort there.  But the loop here is not the bottleneck. The work inside `foo()` is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo & @beaker , without going into details, a short approximation for my problem will be that foo is a trigonometric function, consider `sum(sin(x(:)*y))` there's no way to vectorize the built in `sin` function, or an analytic identity to convert a sum of sines to something elegant. The way out I see is to reduce the length of y, and "histogram" its values, so to have a "lower" resolution, instead of double float, something that is controlled, for example 1e-5...

Comment: The built-in `sin` *is* vectorized, and so is your function `foo()` (because it takes a vector or matrix as input). Tabulating the output of `foo()` and using interpolation to find the value for all your input values might be a good approach, if that provides sufficient precision for your application. Other than that, if you cannot transform the function into something simpler that separates the `x` and `y` of its input, then there is no way around computing the result 1e11 times. That just takes time. It’s not the loop, it’s the computation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I agree, that is what I meant with the sine function - it is built in, cant improve that. The idea to interpolate is cool and might be very useful, but my problem is that values in `y` are really everywhere, there's no simple structure, just upper and lower bounds, interpolation should be tested.

Comment: Rows are independent, so `sum(foo(x(j)*y))`, assuming `foo` is vectorized. You can even use `parfor` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of MATLAB are you using and what on what machine?  I construct vectors of the same size as yours

```
x = linspace(0,1,1000);
y = rand(1,1e8);
```

Sure enough, if I try a direct computation I get a memory error

```
>> A=sum(x(:)*y,2)
Error using  * 
Requested 1000x100000000 (745.1GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference (31.7GB). This might cause MATLAB to
become unresponsive.

Related documentation
```

So I try your loop

```
tic
Asplit=0;
for i=1:length(y)
    Asplit=Asplit+sum(x(:)*y(i),2);
end
toc
```

**This completes in 74 seconds.**  Rather faster than the 45 minutes you quote.
I am using the MATLAB 2023a beta on an 11th Gen Intel. Core(TM) i7-11700 @ 2.50GHz.

I can also get that time down more by using a thread based parpool and a parfor loop

```
parpool('threads');

tic
Asplit=0;
parfor i=1:length(y)
    Asplit=Asplit+sum(x(:)*y(i),2);
end
toc
```

**Down to 15.5 seconds** on my 8 core system. 5x speedup with 8 CPUs.  Not linear scaling but I'll take it.

Also note that I am using double precision here.  You say that you are using single precision.  Let's see what that looks like

```
%try again using single precision
x = single(linspace(0,1,1000));
y = rand(1,1e8,'single');

parpool('threads');

tic
Asplit=0;
parfor i=1:length(y)
    Asplit=Asplit+sum(x(:)*y(i),2);
end
toc
```

**12.8 seconds**.  Faster but is it worth the loss in precision?  I guess that depends on your application.

Finally, let's use the trick `A=x(:)*sum(y)` discussed in the comments by @beaker and others. Compare the result with the split method that we've been looking at so far.

```
x = linspace(0,1,1000);
y = rand(1,1e8);

parpool('threads');

tic
Asplit=0;
parfor i=1:length(y)
    Asplit=Asplit+sum(x(:)*y(i),2);
end
toc

tic
Aalt = x(:)*sum(y);
toc

max(abs(Aalt-Asplit))
```

`x(:)*sum(y)` **took 0.026 seconds** and the largest absolute difference between the two methods was of the order of 1e-6.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. Does anyone have an estimation as to which calculation order (sum(y) first or multiply(x,y) first) would result in higher-precision data (compared to real numbers, which have infinite precision)?

Comment: @XZhang That would depend on the range of magnitudes in `y`, but most likely the order doesn’t matter, both orders will introduce rounding errors. There is no point in doing `length(y)` times as many multiplications in an attempt to avoid a few rounding errors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, I had the same thought. For a given range, the quicker method may also be more accurate. However, 1e-6 in double precision may be regarded pretty huge.

Comment: @XZhang That might be comparing to the single-precision result? I agree, it’s quite a large number.

Answer (score -1):

**1.- memory bottleneck problem**

No matter whatever you do with the complete forms `x` and `y` : if you push such data and operations as shown in the question, 45 minutes wait or **out of memory** warning sure shows up.

**2.- Option 1 : Increase RAM**

One can go as far as the deep is pocket or full is the purse. Good luck with it.

**3.- Option 2 : Parallel Pool**

Good luck with this one too.

**4.- My Suggestion : Break down large variables into processable chunks**

So this is:

- **Break down the variables that jam memory**
- **Operate/process each chunk at a time**
- **Store results in disk**

One way to do this with one of my favourite MATLAB commands : the all-weather, mighty and many-battles-hardened `evalin` (trumpets here)

I tried to break down `y` until I found that 100 pieces of it works. May be larger pieces may work too, but just 4 or 10 may not even start.

```
close all;clear all;clc

x=randi([-1e3 1e3],1,1e3);
y=randi([-1e3 1e3],1,1e8);

N=1e2

A1=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);
A2=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);
A3=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);
A4=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);


k1=2;
L1=['A' num2str(k1) '=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);'];
evalin('base',L1)

tic

for k1=1:N
    
    for k2=1:length(x)/N
        a1=x(k2);
        a2=a1*y(k2);
        L1=['A' num2str(k1) '=zeros(numel(x),numel(y)/N);'];
        evalin('base',L1);
        L2=['A' num2str(k1) '(k2,:)=sum(a2);'];
        evalin('base',L2);
        
        % WRITE Ak1 to FILE
    end

end
```

Replace the line `% WRITE Ak1 to FILE` with something like

```
L3=['']   % build command line into string
evalin('base',L3);  % invoke evalin
```

MATLAB has a diverse array of commands to write and read files, in many formats, for instance .txt and Excel or directly to binary file with command `fwrite` .

To read from file you also have to build strings and invoke them with `evalin` but as shown above, building such concise strings is easy, because all that is done is building variables with code and an varying index has to be embedded in the declaration of such variables, the pieces of y that it has been broken into.

In a nutshell : use variables that can reasonably move in and out of RAM without ending up like that recent Suez canal traffic jam of a vessel blocking every one else.

Comment: `eval` is evil. There is no reason at all to use that here, other than making the code harder to write, harder to read, harder to maintain, and slower to run. Sorry for the downvote, but this is really bad advice, and I hope you stop using this construct as well.

Comment: Hello Chris, that is your opinion. In my opinion evalin is really useful command, I agree with you that it is so within certain constrains, and for very specific problems. Addressing memory bottlenecks avoiding RAM for storage is one cheap yet effective way to avoid jamming the entire system because a variable is too big to process through RAM. In any case, why don't we just leave the question originator to be the one to decide whether to use evalin to use eval or to use any code you post solving or attempting to solve this question?

Comment: Telling the question originator to go and buy and expensive GPU, and spend further in time learning to use it, or telling to go and subscribe to some parallel pool, in my opinion, that wouldn't be really answering the question. The question is 'does any one have some MATLAB code to solve this RAM bottle neck?'

Comment: But you can do exactly the same thing you did without `evalin`. It is.m not necessary there. `eval` and `evalin` have a use, but it’s very specific and niche use case that 99.9% of MATLAB users won’t run into.

Comment: Also, if you read the comments under the question, and the other answer, you can see that OP is doing a very simple operation that can be written in one line without the memory-intensive matrix multiplication. I’m not telling OP to go and buy more RAM.